# ajax, focus and javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function which looks like this.

```
function loadbottom(){
     $("#uploadsegment").load("bottompart.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>&page=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>"); 
}
setInterval (loadbottom, 5000);
```

This function calls a url which generates a form.
However, since it keeps getting refreshed the user can't properly enter text into the form.

I was thinking something like: if(textbox.focus) then dont refresh else refresh. I saw a couple of stackoverflow posts on this topic however none seemed to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: WHy do you need to reload the url over and over?

Comment: Well, I'm checking a field in the database which indicates if a user should be able to write a comment or has to vote on another. I'm using it on my site http://fuzzypinecone.com and since the sites nature the form on the bottom of story.php changes quite often.

Comment: Ok.  My solution should do the job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function loadbottom(){
  $("#uploadsegment").load("bottompart.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>&page=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>", function () {

    $(this).find('input').focus(function () {
      clearInterval(t);
    });

  }); 

}
 var t = setInterval (loadbottom, 5000);
```

Comment: It still doesn't prevent the form from refreshing. http://fuzzypinecone.com/story.php?id=11&book=1